# Live streaming external FLV files

Tags: video, streaming, flash

I want to broadcast live video from a playlist created by me, but the actual video files (.flv's) are stored in some external file hosting which I can't admin, but it's currently allowing the use of flash players for playing its contents (progressively).

Which is the best solution for this? Can I use my current web server (Debian w/Apache) or should I use some specific server software? I've read some names such as Red5 and Wowza but I can't tell if those are solutions to my actual problem or how should I use them. Also, costs should be as low as possible for this project.

Comment: You say you want to broadcast live video, but FLVs by nature are pre-recorded. Do you mean that you just want to stream the video once?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CDN with RTMP & RTMPT Flash Streaming, for example [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/),  [SimpleCDN](http://www.simplecdn.com/solutions), etc.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more in the practical implementation? or a link to somewhere exposing my specific problem?

Comment: Also http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/faqs/#Does_CloudFront_support_live_streaming

Answer (score 0):

Use flvstreamer and [ffserver](http://ffmpeg.org/sample.html).

flvstreamer does what it sounds like, and ffserver comes with ffmpeg, and it lets you stream live video from anything you can feed into ffmpeg like this:

```
flvstreamer url | ffmpeg  -i - http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed1.ffm
```

ffserver can "output" a flash stream- a url that you'd visit like http://site/video.swf or you can offer other formats (like asf or mpg) and ffmpeg can transcode it- if your computer is fast enough- in real time.

Then your "playlist" is essentially a list of `flvserver|ffmpeg...` commands, and it's very easy to add more, or add more streams.

Below is a configuration file that I use. Some things to note: the feed1.ffm is a "buffer", and the "max size" is essentially how lagged things can get. Removing the `FileMaxSize` records everything, allowing you to time-shift your video as well.

```
Port 8090
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxClients 200
MaxBandwidth 4000000
<Feed feed1.ffm>
File tmp/feed1.ffm
FileMaxSize 10M
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Feed>
<Stream video.swf>
Feed feed1.ffm
VideoBitRate 500
VideoBufferSize 40
VideoGopSize 10
Format swf
VideoSize 640x480
VideoFrameRate 10
VideoQMin  1
VideoQMax  4
VideoHighQuality
NoAudio
PreRoll 0
StartSendOnKey
</Stream>
```